# The module cannot be Android Library?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for Android Development, and when I try to edit the run configuration for the Android emulator, it says there is an error and it looks like this.

[image]

The emulator still runs but it doesn't launch the activity automatically and I'm just wondering what's causing this error and what are possible solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like "SpyMaze" is an Android library project, so you can't run a library project, 
[check this out](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

Comment: That link points to an Eclipse page. Did you mean to point to an IntelliJ page, such as [Choosing the module type you need](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-android-support.html)?

Answer (score 3):

That happened to me too after following the Android Studio recommendations to switch "android" to "com.android.library in build.gradle.

So for the app module of my project, I just reverted this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Into this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: Fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 2):

GO to "Project structure" icon (it is enlisting where your new,save project icons are showing) then click Module and select Android option and Uncheck Library Module
or

> PROJECT STRUCTURE->MODULE->ANDROID->UNCHECK LIBRARY

Answer (score 2):

For an `InstantApp` - check that you run `app`, and not one of your `features` solely. Choose `app` on Android Studio bar to Run.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because you are trying to run module library as an application.

If you want to run as application you need to add below in SpyMaze module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

If you are using SpyMaze module as a library keep

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

And in edit configurations select main app. So you should see Run 'app' and not Run 'SpyMaze'

Answer (score 1):

Also if you added a new module/library don't forget to change back to the right project before you press `Run`.

[image]